# Any alternate way to call db2 procedure which has input param Array row type?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, db2-luw

I'm trying to pass array of row type as input to store procedure from jdbc.

Have written below code and getting "Method createStruct" is not supported in connection.

Table:

```
create table wspout.test (username varchar(100),location varchar(100),status varchar(100));
```

Row Type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_ROW AS ROW ANCHOR ROW OF test;
```

Array Row Type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_ROW_ARRAY AS TEST_ROW ARRAY[];
```

Store procedure Name:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROC (IN p_test_row_array TEST_ROW_ARRAY)
P1: BEGIN
DECLARE i INTEGER;
DECLARE v_test_row TEST_ROW;
SET i = 1;
WHILE i < CARDINALITY(p_test_row_array) DO
    SET v_test_row = p_test_row_array[i];
    insert into test values(v_test_row.username,v_test_row.location,v_test_row.status);
    set i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END P1@
```

my java class: from here calling the store procedure

```
package Test;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Struct;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestJdbc{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
      Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("DB2 driver is loaded successfully");
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://localhost:40000/db2inst1","test","test123");
        if (conn != null)
        {
        System.out.println("DB2 Database Connected");


        List<Object> test_row_List = new ArrayList<>();
        Struct test_row[] = new java.sql.Struct[3];
        Array test_row_arr;        

        test_row[0] = conn.createStruct("TEST_ROW", new Object[] { "user1","Location1", "status1"});
        test_row_List.add(test_row[0]);

        test_row[1] = conn.createStruct("TEST_ROW", new Object[] { "user2","Location2", "status2"});
        test_row_List.add(test_row[1]);

        test_row[2] = conn.createStruct("TEST_ROW", new Object[] { "user3","Location3", "status4"});
        test_row_List.add(test_row[2]);

        test_row_arr = conn.createArrayOf("TEST_ROW", test_row_List.toArray());

        System.out.println("Array value" + test_row_arr);

        pstmt = conn.prepareCall("CALL TEST_PROC(?)");                      
        pstmt.setArray(1, test_row_arr);
        pstmt.execute();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("DB2 Database connection e");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }


  }
```

while running i'm getting below exception .

```
*DB2 driver is loaded successfully
DB2 Database Connected
DB2 Database connection e
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlFeatureNotSupportedException: [jcc][t4][10181][12052][4.11.69] Method createStruct is not supported. ERRORCODE=-4450, SQLSTATE=0A504*
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.e(gd.java:605)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.c(gd.java:625)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.lb.createStruct(lb.java:6761)
    at Test.TestJdbc.main(TestJdbc.java:38)
```

Comment: What Db2 version are you connecting to? Your JDBC driver version is quite old.

Comment: You mean in your jdbc version you are able to proceed further?

Comment: No, I mean exactly what I wrote above.

Comment: jdbc version -  db2jcc4.jar - IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.11.69
db version - DB2 v10.1.0.872

Comment: I suggest you upgrade your driver to [version 4.15.146](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866) at least, or may be even more recent.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Invoking stored procedures with ARRAY of ROW parameters in JDBC applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_tjv00002.html):

```
...
//PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
CallableStatement pstmt = null;
...
//java.util.List<Object> test_row_List = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
// Actually it's not needed at all
java.util.List<Object> test_row_List = new java.util.ArrayList<Object>();
...
//test_row_arr = con.createArrayOf("TEST_ROW", test_row_List.toArray());
test_row_arr = con.createArrayOf("TEST_ROW", test_row);
...
```

And you should use the following, unless you really want to insert all the rows in the array but the latest.

> WHILE i **<=** CARDINALITY(p_test_row_array)